# Node/website architecture visualization

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, navigation

I am seeking to build a website which contains quite a lot of information. All this information will be structured in a specific way. As such I am looking for a way to represent this data/articles/nodes visually.

The purpose is to be able to add new articles to an already existing visual structure by simply adding a node and classifying it/linking to existing articles that are already structured/adding taxonomy terms etc.

The visual structure will as such have a changing shape/size. A map of the information presented on the site if you will.

A way to navigate the wealth of information visually.

Does something like this already exist or is there a way to create such a module/program for the site - potentially as a separate site that presents the drupal site?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a Drupal specific option, but you can utilize a module like [XML Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap):

> The XML sitemap module creates a sitemap that conforms to the
>   sitemaps.org specification. This helps search engines to more
>   intelligently crawl a website and keep their results up to date. The
>   sitemap created by the module can be automatically submitted to Ask,
>   Google, Bing (formerly Windows Live Search), and Yahoo! search
>   engines. The module also comes with several submodules that can add
>   sitemap links for content, menu items, taxonomy terms, and user
>   profiles.

and then use a number of third party online or software based options for visualising xml data.  A quick search in google yielded a number of options for 'visualise sitemap'

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Geoff's answer (which is an stroke of genius), note that you can link nodes using [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference), and create heirarchies of nodes using [Node Hierarchy](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy).

I recommend the former unless you *really* need to specify which node is parent and which is child, in which case the latter works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the often forgotten book module which is part of Drupal core. It allows for nesting of nodes inside other nodes so you can create a book with chapters. ([the guide pages on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/documentation) are an example of this.) depending on the stucture you need this could be useful.